# If gravity interacts with light just by changing the wavelength of light why a BH does not emit EM-waves even of extremely low frequencies?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, speed-of-light, redshift

If gravity interacts with light just by changing the wavelength of light why a BH does not emit EM-waves even  of extremely low frequency? A neutron star does the gravitational redshift of light but it atleast emits that light...

Comment: Gravity does not only change wavelength. You may be interested in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole#Event_horizon) article on black holes.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean. The light emission process in a neutron star is a different process from the gravitational redshift. It is not that the gravity of a neutron star is emitting light

Comment: @LucasBaldo The matter of a collapsed star always remains outside the horizon in our coordinates, so conceptually we can receive its emission forever +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an object emitting EM radiation as it approaches a black hole, the frequency detected by a distant observer will approach zero as the object approaches the event horizon.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not to the point. Black holes do emit large wavelength EM signal named as 'Hawking Radiation' named after Stephen Hawking who discovered it.
Now Let's come to what you may want to ask-Why doesn't light escape the Black hole, even of very large wavelength? Well again the answer is quite simple, nothing can escape the Event Horizon of the black hole. Reason is very obvious from the equation:[image]

According to our current knowledge there is a singularity at the centre of a Black hole. A singularity is a very big mass in a very small volume (Meaning radius).According to general realtivity singularity in a infinitely small point with no surface area(basically no radius). But lets stick to the point, you need to move faster than the speed of light to escape it.We know that Electromagnetic radiation travel at the speed of light so they basically cannot escape a black hole (Actually nothing can).Well you should study about 'Photon sphere' ,It will give you more insights about behaviour of light near a black hole.